# Update chosen-select knockout binding whenever changes are made to another knockout binding

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-binding-handlers

**I have the following scenario:**

I have a table with to multiple select input boxes (`chosen.jquery`).

```
<select multiple data-bind="
    chosen: $parent.SelectableOptions, 
    optionsText: 'Title', 
    optionsValue: 'InternalName', 
    chosenSelectedOptions: SelectedFields, 
    chosenEnable: Enabled" class="chzn-select"></select>

<select multiple data-bind="
    chosen: SelectedFields, 
    optionsText: 'Title', 
    optionsValue: 'InternalName', 
    chosenSelectedOptions: SelectedReadOnlyFields, 
    chosenEnable: Enabled" class="chzn-select"></select>
```

Notice the `chosenSelectedOptions` binding in the first select input. This is bound to `SelectedFields`. This is an array, and this is the exact array that I wish to ad as possible options for the second select input. This can be seen by noticing the `chosen` binding for the second select input: `SelectedFields`.

The fields selected in the second select input, should be added to a new array called `SelectedReadOnlyFields` and stated in the `chosenSelectedOptions` binding.

**Problem**

As I'm fairly new to KnockoutJS, I'm not sure where to go from here, or how to set this up correctly. Whenever the `SelectedFields` array changes, I wish to update the possible options in the second select input, but I can't get this to work. I've read posts that mentions the following way to trigger an update on the chosen select input (`$(element).trigger('chosen:updated')`), but as I do not have an id on the second select input, I cannot locate that element.

**EXTRA**

Bindings in topic:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.chosen = {
    init: function (element) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.init(element);
        $(element).chosen({ disable_search_threshold: 1000, allow_single_deselect: true, width: "100%" });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.options.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
        $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
};

ko.bindingHandlers.chosenSelectedOptions = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.selectedOptions.init(element, valueAccessor);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
        ko.bindingHandlers.selectedOptions.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
        $(element).trigger('chosen:updated');
    }
};
```